# Grid with a number

Tags: grids

I know how to create a grid by using TikZ and the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,table]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,plotmarks}
\def\quadrill#1{\smallbreak\textcolor{gray}     {\setlength\unitlength{5mm}\begin{picture}(36,#1)
\multiput(0,0)(1,0){37}{\line(0,1){#1}}
\put(0,0){\line(1,0){36}}
\multiput(0,1)(0,1){#1}{\line(1,0){36}}
\end{picture}}\medbreak}

\newenvironment{Quadrill}[1]{\quadrill#1}{}

\begin{document}
\Quadrill{12}   
\end{document}
```

My aim is now to add a counter, for example a big number in the upper left corner area of my grids. Unfortunately, I am not able to adapt the previous code.

Comment: I'm confused. You are loading Ti*k*Z but seem not to make use of it. Would you be interested in a Ti*k*Z based solution?

Comment: A solution using Tikz would be as good. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,table]{book}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\quadrill}[2][]{\smallbreak\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[gray]
\draw (0,0) grid[step={\linewidth/36}] (\linewidth,{\linewidth/36});
\node[anchor=south west,gray] at (0,{\linewidth/36}) {#2};
\end{tikzpicture}\medbreak}
\newenvironment{Quadrill}[1]{\quadrill{#1}}{}

\begin{document}
\Quadrill{12}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works fine. I just changed a little bit the code in order to print and to increment automatically the counter together with the section.

Comment: @jowe_19 If the solution worked for you please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) and perhaps [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: \newcounter{NoQuadrill}
    \newcommand{\quadrill}[1]{\smallbreak\begin{tikzpicture}    [scale=0.5,gray]
    \draw(0,0) grid (34,#1);
    \node[anchor=north west] at (31.5,1.1)     {\color{blue}\bfseries\Large{\thesection.\theNoQuadrill}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\medbreak}
    \newenvironment{Quadrill}[1]    {\refstepcounter{NoQuadrill}\quadrill{#1}}{}

Comment: @jowe_19 That's all very nice, but was that part of your question?